# Can something like a Donkey Sentence exist in a programming language?

Tags: parsing, semantics

I am interested, whether, in some programming language, there can be something like a [Donkey Sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey_sentence), a sentence that defies straightforward attempts to translate it into a formal language, but is nevertheless meaningful?

An example of a Donkey Sentence is "*Every farmer who owns a donkey beats it.*", a straightforward attempt to translate it into a formal language would be:
$$\forall x. (\mathrm{FARMER}(x) \land \exists y. (\mathrm{DONKEY}(y) \land \mathrm{OWNS}(x, y)) \to \mathrm{BEAT}(x, y))$$

But that's not a valid sentence ("y" at the end is out of scope).

A correct translation seems to be:

$$\forall x. \forall y. ((\mathrm{FARMER}(x) \land \mathrm{DONKEY}(y) \land \mathrm{OWNS}(x, y)) \to \mathrm{BEAT}(x, y))$$

But it's not obvious how it follows from the syntax of the sentence (notice that the translation says "all donkeys", whereas the original sentence says "a donkey").

In my [Bachelor Thesis](https://flatassembler.github.io/PicoBlaze/PicoBlaze.rtf), on page 13, I claim that there isn't. However, given how diverse programming languages are, I am not really sure. Can there be such a sentence in some declarative (rather than imperative) language?

Sentences such as "*More people have been to Russia than I have.*" (that seem acceptable at first although they are ungrammatical) obviously can exist in programming languages: ungrammatical expression `5**`, in the first versions of [my AEC-to-x86 compiler](https://flatassembler.github.io/compiler), passed through the parser (producing the AST `(* 5 *)`) and crashed the compiler. Sentences such as "*Time flies like an arrow.*" (where without context it is unclear which word is of which type and so can be parsed in different ways because of that) can also exist in some programming languages, that's what's the *typedef problem* is about. So I am wondering whether Donkey Sentences can exist in some programming language.

Comment: You can certainly create statements that don't do anything useful but but the example you give seems more like a bug

Comment: I don't see two different ways of parsing "time flies like an arrow", but "fruit flies like a banana" definitely has two possible meanings.

Comment: Could you add an example of a donkey sentence to the question? The linked Wikipedia article is helpful, but it would be better if people don't have to read an external source to understand the question.

Comment: My favourite one is "I saw the man on the hill with the telescope".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey_sentence):

> Barker and Shan define a donkey pronoun as "a pronoun that lies outside the restrictor of a quantifier or the if-clause of a conditional, yet covaries with some quantificational element inside it, usually an indefinite."[3]

The sentence *"Every farmer who owns a donkey beats it"* seems to be a prototypical example. Here the pronoun "it" refers to the donkey that the farmer owns, but this pronoun occurs outside of the clause *"farmer who owns a donkey"* in the parse tree of the sentence where its referent exists.

So, can programming languages have sentences like this? In a trivial sense, the answer is no ─ a "donkey sentence" is defined by the use of a variable outside of its scope, and that is definitively an error. But this is tautological; the scope of a name *means* the places that name can be used.

A more interesting way of looking at it is whether the scope of some names can be expanded so that they can be used in more places, allowing the language to express things like donkey sentences can in natural language. Put another way, in a donkey sentence the pronoun refers to something outside of the clause where that pronoun's referent is declared, but the pronoun still has meaning outside of that clause because its scope *is* broader than the parse tree would suggest.

Consider pattern matching:

```rust
match donkey {
    Some(d) if farmer.owns(d) => assert!(farmer.beats(d)),
    _ => {},
}
```

Here the name `d` is declared in the pattern `Some(d) if farmer.owns(d)`, and used in the expression `farmer.beats(d)` which is not a sub-expression of that pattern. That is, the pattern declaring `d` and the expression using `d` are separate, non-overlapping nodes in the parse tree. But nonetheless the language defines that the scope of a variable bound in a pattern includes the right-hand-side of the `match` arm where that pattern occurs, and hence `d` is in scope where it is used.

So it seems to be subject to interpretation whether this is really analogous to a donkey sentence, but also I'm not sure there is much value for programming language designers in figuring that out. Maybe it's a more interesting question for linguists or philosophers interested in correspondences between natural and artificial languages.

Comment: The value would lie in the fact that most beginner programmers try to use a local variable after it has left its scope. Donkey sentences make sense in real life. Learning that they don't in programming can be difficult.

Comment: @shawnhcorey Sure, there is value in widening the scope of variables so they can be used in more places, so long as widening the scope makes sense to do so. What I don't see much value in is figuring out whether code which makes use of such wider scopes is really "like a donkey sentence" or not; that's a philosophical point.

Comment: You missed the part about beginner programmers. Humans can easily parse Donkey Sentences. That is why beginners programmers often make this mistake. If a compiler can figure out how to do the same thing, it would be easier to learn programming.

Comment: @shawnhcorey I didn't miss that part. Beginner programmers won't benefit from a debate over whether a particular scoping rule is "like a donkey sentence", any more than they would benefit from a debate over how many angels can dance on the head of a pin.

Comment: @shawnhcorey Beginner programmers make lots of mistakes, like `if a == "foo" or "bar":` when it should be `if a == "foo" or a == "bar":`, because they expect the programming language to be parsed like English. So unless your objective is to design a language that's more English-like (e.g. COBOL) so that beginners are less likely to make mistakes like this, it's not clear how interesting this is.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure this is answering your question but...

### Programming languages are generally designed to be unambiguous

With the exception of some [esoteric languages](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Main_Page) programming language are generally designed to have one unique interpretation* <sup>(at least per compiler)</sup>

Programming languages are to give instructions to a computer.
Unlike human languages they do not normally contain any intentional ambiguity.

##### C++

C++ has a [Most_vexing_parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) which is ambiguous at the pure syntax level.
You can't tell if a symbol is a variable or function in certian forms but this only lasts until you can place it in the symbol table.
C++ compilers often feed information back into the lexical and syntactic stages to do with this.
C++ has a context sensitive grammar but its interpretion is still unambiguous
(caveat deliberately undefined behaviour).

##### Prolog

Prolog is a logic language whose operation is to search through a space of predicates. For instance if you construct a predicate to solve the `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle`. Say:

```
queens(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h): 
   ...
```

It has 92 solutions so it seems ambiguous. But this predicate will typically give you each one in turn in a deterministic order so it doesn't really qualify.